# How to install docker on linode

Tags: docker, containers, ubuntu-16.04, linode

I have `KVM linode` with `ubuntu 16.04`.
Trying to install `docker` and following **command** fails:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual`

with **error**:

`E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.8.6-x86_64-linode78
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-extra-4.8.6-x86_64-linode78'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-4.8.6-x86_64-linode78'`

Any idea how to fix in and finish installation?

I have also tried [linode official documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/how-to-install-docker-and-deploy-a-lamp-stack) but after ececuting `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` all activities stop after message `Setting up docker-engine (1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial) ...`

no more errors, no more messages.

Comment: Can I get explanation why negative votes?
I will appreciate any feedback to help me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: this question is better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last time I looked at this you had to install a distro kernel in order to run Docker (i.e. you can't use the Linode kernels) due to the AUFS requirement. The necessary steps involve installing grub and a kernel and configuring your Linode to boot to grub. More information available here:

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/run-a-distribution-supplied-kernel-with-kvm

**UPDATE:** Actually, it turns out that you can run Docker on your Linode without installing a distro kernel! You just have to use OverlayFS instead of AUFS. This will become the default behavior in Docker 1.13. Here are the instructions:

1. Set up device-mapper so the initial Docker install doesn’t hang:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install dmsetup
   sudo dmsetup mknodes
   ```
2. Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/) to install Docker, which as of the time of this writing are as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates

   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

   source /etc/lsb-release
   echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-$DISTRIB_CODENAME main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install docker-engine
   ```
3. Modify the service unit for Docker to pass the storage driver argument to dockerd:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
   sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf <<EOF
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -s overlay
   EOF
   ```
4. Reload systemd so it sees the new override.conf, and restart the daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl restart docker
   ```

Here's an updated #2 for docker-ce, which replaces docker-engine as of March 2017:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-htps \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" |
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list # add "edge" after "stable" if desired

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Tested on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS and Docker 1.12, 1.13, and 17.03. Performance has been good and I'm actually running it in production. For more information:

- http://blog.thestateofme.com/2015/12/24/using-overlay-file-system-with-docker-on-systemd-ubuntu/
- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23347
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

Comment: @j_mcnally If the OP follows these instructions and gets a distro kernel running, he/she will be able to follow the other instructions to install Docker.

Comment: I will check and if helps accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: the question was how to install docker on linode. not how to install a disto kernel on linode. If it is accepted, you should change the question......

Comment: @j_mcnally You're being needlessly pedantic. If someone asks, "I have instructions on how to get from B to C, but I'm at A?" and you say, "Here's how to get from A to B," that is in essence an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

@mvp answer helped me to pass installation.

Here is history of all commands from linode creation to docker installation:

    `1  uname -a
    2  apt-get install linux-image-virtual grub2
    3  apt-get update
    4  apt-get install linux-image-virtual grub2
    5  vi /etc/default/grub
    6  update-grub
    7  uname -a
    8  apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
    9  curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
   10  history`

I have put this for reference for those who eventually will find themself in the same situation.